# using groupby().sum() result to manipulate the original data frame

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like a transactions

```
    branch      daqu  from    to       style  color  size  amount
5  huadong  shanghai  C30C  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   165       3
8  huadong  shanghai  C30F  C306  EEBW52301M     51   160       2
2  huadong  shanghai  C30G  C306  EEBW52301M     39   165      10
9  huadong  shanghai  C30G  C30C  EEBW52301M     51   170       1
1  huadong  shanghai  C30G  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   160       7
7  huadong  shanghai  C30J  C30D  EEBW52301M     39   170       2
6  huadong  shanghai  C30J  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   170       4
3  huadong  shanghai  C30K  C306  EEBW52301M     39   165       1
0  huadong  shanghai  C30K  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   160       7
4  huadong  shanghai  C30K  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   165       6
```

The data means that we have to send 'amount' amount of style/color/size product from 'from' store to 'to' store.

Then what I did was groupby 'from' and 'to' so I can see how many products will be put in each boxes.

```
print dh_final[['from', 'to', 'amount']].groupby(['from', 'to']).sum()

            amount
from to          
C30C C30F       3
C30F C306       2
C30G C306      10
     C30C       1
     C30F       7
C30J C30D       2
     C30F       4
C30K C306       1
     C30F      13
```

Last, if the box from one store to another have less than 5 product, I want to cancel the transaction related with that box. That is I have to delete rows from the original dataframe. If I do it manually the result should look something like this.

```
    branch      daqu  from    to       style  color  size  amount
2  huadong  shanghai  C30G  C306  EEBW52301M     39   165      10
1  huadong  shanghai  C30G  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   160       7
0  huadong  shanghai  C30K  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   160       7
4  huadong  shanghai  C30K  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   165       6
```

Is there any simple way to do this? How can I use the result of groupby().sum() to manipulate the original dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want this:

```
In [53]:
df['sum'] = df.groupby(['from', 'to'])['amount'].transform('sum')
df[df['sum'] > 5]

Out[53]:
    branch      daqu  from    to       style  color  size  amount  sum
2  huadong  shanghai  C30G  C306  EEBW52301M     39   165      10   10
1  huadong  shanghai  C30G  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   160       7    7
0  huadong  shanghai  C30K  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   160       7   13
4  huadong  shanghai  C30K  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   165       6   13
```

So here I call `transform` on the `groupby` object to return a series aligned with original df to add the 'sum' column, I can then filter the df as usual.

**EDIT**

Actually I think you can just do this as a one-liner:

```
In [67]:
df[df.groupby(['from', 'to'])['amount'].transform('sum') > 5]

Out[67]:
    branch      daqu  from    to       style  color  size  amount
2  huadong  shanghai  C30G  C306  EEBW52301M     39   165      10
1  huadong  shanghai  C30G  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   160       7
0  huadong  shanghai  C30K  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   160       7
4  huadong  shanghai  C30K  C30F  EEBW52301M     39   165       6
```